# CCAvenue Payment Gateway Advanced for WooCommerce Amount Wrong

Tags: ccavenue

Hello i use CCAvenue Payment Gateway Advanced for WooCommerce plug in for payment gateway when i click to pay then **remaining amount** is not show in total amount its show **Deposit** amount. i want to display remaining amount. how can i do that?

I tried to change some functionality in plug-in but there is no any result found..

How can i display remaining amount in total amount in CCAvenue Payment Gateway..

Please help me in this situations!!!!

Comment: did you got the answer?